# Join logic between tables without an obvious join condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, view

I've got 2 tables, one with an area, actions and quantities, and the other with prices and the goal is to combine the two in a view

table1

```
 areaid integer
 bananaunits  integer
 kilometers_ran  integer
 dogecoins  integer

areaid | bananaunits | kilometers_ran | dogecoin
1 | 0 | 1 | 10
2 | 4 | 2 | 100
```

table2

```
rateid integer
description text 
cost_per_unit integer

rateid | description | cost_per_unit
1 | price per banana | 0.5
2 | price per kilometers run | 2
3 | price per doge | 1
```

The intended outcome is to have a view which has the fields as following:

areaid, rateid, description, cost_per_unit, units, combined_cost

```
areaid| rateid| description| cost_per_unit| units| total_cost
1 | 1 | price per banana | 0.5 | 0 | 0
1 | 2 | per kilometers run | 2 | 1 | 2
1 | 3 | price per doge | 1 | 10 | 10
2 | 1 | price per banana | 0.5 | 4 | 2
2 | 2 | per kilometers run | 2 | 2 | 4
2 | 3 | price per doge | 1 | 100 | 100
```

In other words, I need to present all the rates per area in individual rows. how to achieve this?

Edit: current query that doesnt work

select   areaid, rateid, description, cost_per_unit, units, combined_cost from table1,table2

Comment: Moving parts of column names to row elements & moving row elements into column names are called pivoting & unpivoting. PS Unpivoted data is generally a bad design, when you have parameterized structure the parameter should be a column.

Comment: @philipxy if you mean moving the items in table1 into the output as rows, the reason is simple, there are many more calculations that needs to be done per item and there are many items, so the output would easily baloon to 300 columns otherwise

Comment: What I said was that table1 should not have unit type run across its column names but that it should have columns for id & type. (Like table2.) But given the table1 you have, find out how to pivot.

Comment: @philipxy table1 is an aggregation table of multiple tables, each column has a condition which sometimes depends on several tables. Its purpose is to count features per area

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Your comment is more fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a joining key and you want a row for each of combination of the `area` and `rates`, you're basically looking for a [CROSS JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/queries-table-expressions.html) also called cartesian product

Comment: how to associate the prices to the units without using case?

Comment: It's not a cross join, output total_cost is not an input value. But the question doesn't say what it wants. But when clear it will be a faq.

Comment: @philipxy what do you mean "question doesnt say" ..? I literally posted the intended outcome

Comment: @Luffydude You give 1 example of output for input. You don't say what it's an example of. You give some unclear prose fragments re how output is a function of input. You say "in other words", but what follows (a fragment) isn't in other words, because you haven't given it "in words" yet. You expect us to guess the function from that 1 case. PS [mre] PS Please show what parts you can do. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: @philipxy It's an example of what I intended to do? (not sure what you want me to say). I want to calculate using the rates in table2 per area on table1 as I've said "in words". I can't do it, hence the question. I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean with "business relation" in sql, again the intended output is to represent all the rates for each item per area

Comment: @Luffydude You haven't said it in words, in your post or comment. So it's no wonder you can't say it in code. I told you how to say it in words (in a way that directly corresponds to cod.e. (I didn't say "business relation", see what I said.) A row (areaid, ...) is in the output when/iff there are some values for t1.* where row (t1.areaid, ...) in table1 & areaid=t1.areaid & ... ? And if that mentions the business situation then you need to say, a row (areaid...) is in table1 when/iff area areaid ... has ... .